# What am I missing to define a variable from a page object? Getting undefined error in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I'm trying to create a page object for the forms I'm automating and getting undefined local variable or method for 'checkout_form', though I thought I've already defined the variable.

This is my page object page:

```
    require "page-object"

    class CheckoutForm
        include PageObject

        # Checkout page
        # Billing info
        text_field(:billingfirst, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_FirstName')
        text_field(:billingmiddle, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_MiddleInitial')
        text_field(:billinglast, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_Lastname')
        text_field(:billingaddress, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_Address1')
        text_field(:billingaddress2, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_Address2')
        text_field(:billingcity, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_City')
        text_field(:billingstate, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_State')
        text_field(:billingzip, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_ZipCode')
        text_field(:billingphone, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_Phone')
        text_field(:billingemail, :id => 'CheckOut_BillingTag_Email')

        def billing_info( billingfirst, billingmiddle, billinglast, billingaddress, billingaddress2, billingcity, billingstate, billingzip, billingphone, billingemail ) 
            self.billingfirst = billingfirst
            self.billingmiddle = billingmiddle
            self.billinglast = billinglast
            self.billingaddress = billingaddress
            self.billingaddress2 = billingaddress2
            self.billingcity = billingcity
            self.billingstate = billingstate
            self.billingzip = billingzip
            self.billingphone = billingphone
            self.billingemail = billingemail
        end
    end
```

On a different page that will use the page object I've added ' require_relative "checkout-form.rb" '

And there I set up the driver:

```
@b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
checkout_form = CheckoutForm.new(@b)
```

And interacting with the pageobject methods here:

```
    checkout_form.billing_info.set 'Mike', 'L', 'Jones', '13677 Ruette Le Parc', 'Unit G', 'Del Mar', 'CA', '92014', 'aaaaa', 'mike.jones@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling checkout_form in the same scope you declared it? It would help if you showed the usage in relation to the declaration.

Comment: I just moved the page object class over to the same page as the script and still the same results, so no it's not being called in the same scope.

The second part I'm kind of not understanding.

Comment: My second point was to help identify if the scope was the same. For example, is the `checkout_form = CheckoutForm.new(@b)` being called in the same method as `checkout_form.billing_info`? Basically showing the entire script where you do these 2 lines would help.

Comment: Ah! I really need to understand Ruby syntax and that def is Ruby method and it =/= object necessarily (stuck in other language mindset). 

It wasn't, I just moved it over to the method I need it to work on and it does now.

Thank you for your help in making me realize if it was in the same method.